# Keeping the same variables in a structure in c

Tags: c, structure

In my main function, I scan the information of a file and put all of the information into a global structure. However, whenever I go to another function and declare my structure, all of the information I had put in it disappears. I would like to know how to make all of the values I put into my structure stay the same in every function.
Structure:

```
struct joueursstruct
{
int numero;
char equipe[4];
char prenom[50];
char nom[50];
int buts;
int assist;
int penal;
int points;
}joueurs2[50];
```

Main part that scans file

```
for(indice1 = 0;indice1 < 50;indice1++)
{
    fscanf(fptr,"%d",&joueurs2[indice1].numero);
    fscanf(fptr,"%c",&buffer);
    fscanf(fptr,"%[^ ]s",&joueurs2[indice1].equipe);
    fscanf(fptr,"%c",&buffer);
    fscanf(fptr,"%[^ ]s",&joueurs2[indice1].prenom);
    fscanf(fptr,"%c",&buffer);
    fscanf(fptr,"%[^ ]s",&joueurs2[indice1].nom);
    fscanf(fptr,"%d",&joueurs2[indice1].buts);
    fscanf(fptr,"%c",&buffer);
    fscanf(fptr,"%d",&joueurs2[indice1].assist);
    fscanf(fptr,"%c",&buffer);
    fscanf(fptr,"%d",&joueurs2[indice1].penal);
    joueurs2[indice1].points = joueurs2[indice1].buts + 
    joueurs2[indice1].assist;
}
```

Part of other function that is supposed to print names and goals of players on screen:

```
{
 printf("%d\t %s\t %s\t %s %d\t %d\t %d\t %d\n", 
 joueurs2[indice1].numero,joueurs2[indice1].equipe,joueurs2[indice1].prenom
 ,joueurs2[indice1].nom,joueurs2[indice1].buts,joueurs2[indice1].assist,
 joueurs2[indice1].penal,joueurs2[indice1].points);
}
```

But all it does is print 0s.

Comment: Show us some code...

Comment: See [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: It looks like you're creating multiple variables, hence not sharing the same data. But it's difficult to tell.

Comment: Put all the function: let us see the variables you declared there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you declare a same-named variable in your function? Then it creates a local object, and its name shadows the global one. Remove that declaration from the function and see the effect. If your compiler then complains about undefined identifier, then put that global variable declaration *before* the function.